# Second autorun at Windows startup

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

My program needs 2 system reboots to complete its work.
I want to use HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce registry key to autorun my program.
Sequence of operations:

- Write itself to RunOnce key
- Reboot
- Autorun and do some stuff.
- Write itself to RunOnce key
- Reboot
- Complete work

But [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says: "A program run from any of these keys should not write to the key during its execution".

How can I start my program automatically after second reboot?

After first reboot: how my program can ask system to autorun it after reboot if it is forbidden to write to RunOnce because program already run from RunOnce?

Comment: there is literallly no need to fiddle with the registry : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446817(v=vs.85).aspx

Registry manipulations are error-prone and can lead to system-lockups, even data-loss in the worst of cases, it is best to avoid the registry altogether because although it has been widely used for over a decade now it never was intended as pseudo-API - there are better ways to achieve your tasks but im guessing they wont matter until your software is used in a productive environement

Comment: @specializt: The "registy warnings" are intended to scare average users. Developers are supposed to be capable of not messing up.

Comment: Does MSDN forbid changing only RunOnce key or Run key too? It is not clear. If autorun program can change Run key, I can use it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to point the autorun to a batch file. You can alter the batch file anyway you like between reboots.

The better solution is of course to eliminate at least one of those 2 reboots. Even if you're installing a new file system driver, one reboot should suffice.

Answer (score -1):

At exit of your application A you can start a new application B to add the original application A to RunOnce. Application B can even the same as A but run with a command line switch to do RunOnce registration only and bypass the normal execution path.

Comment: That does not solve the problem.  The RunOnce key is still being modified while it is being processed, and that is what Microsoft wants to avoid.